# What's the effect of projection layer after n-grams convolution banks?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm studying CBHG module for extracting representations from sequence in  Tacotron.

CBHG is consisted of (1-D convolution bank - highway network - bidirectional GRU).

Inputs of 1-d conv is made by 'lookup_table' for embedding a~z.
After 1-D conv caculate, there is 'tf.concat' for concated the results.
And there is projection with this result.

I think it's associate with word2vec embedding like 'CBOW' but It's very hard to me.

What is the effect of projection layer after concated result by n-grams convolution? Extracting meaningful 'n' in n-grams conv banks?

Please help me.

```
with tf.variable_scope('conv_bank'):
        # Convolution bank: concatenate on the last axis
        # to stack channels from all convolutions
        conv_fn = lambda k: \
                conv1d(inputs, k, bank_channel_size, 
                        tf.nn.relu, is_training, 'conv1d_%d' % k)

        conv_outputs = tf.concat(
            [conv_fn(k) for k in range(1, bank_size+1)], axis=-1,
        )

    # Maxpooling:
    maxpool_output = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(
        conv_outputs,
        pool_size=maxpool_width,
        strides=1,
        padding='same')

    # Two projection layers:
    proj_out = maxpool_output
    for idx, proj_size in enumerate(proj_sizes):
        activation_fn = None if idx == len(proj_sizes) - 1 else tf.nn.relu
        proj_out = conv1d(
                proj_out, proj_width, proj_size, activation_fn,
                is_training, 'proj_{}'.format(idx + 1))
```